# Is it well-defined to cast xvalues to lvalues for passing to functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, c++14

[Recently I've discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26793072/1000282)
that sometimes being able to turn rvalues *temporarily* into lvalues can be
useful for me.

I've been using the following tool:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
inline constexpr std::remove_reference_t<T> &lvalue(T &&r) noexcept {
    return static_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T> &>(r);
}
```

It's useful when you have to use functions that require lvalues as
arguments, but you don't have any interest in what those particular
values get changed into. For when you are interested in other output
vectors that are not related to the given specific argument.

For example, this:

```
std::string get_my_file() {
    std::ifstream ifs("myfile.txt");
    return {std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {}};
}
```

can be changed to this:

```
std::string get_my_file() {
    return {std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(lvalue(std::ifstream("myfile.txt"))),
            {}};
}
```

And this:

```
std::string temp1 = get_my_shader();
const char *temp2 = temp1.c_str();
glShaderSource(a, 1, &temp2, nullptr);
```

can be changed to this:

```
glShaderSource(a, 1, &lvalue(get_my_shader().c_str()), nullptr);
```

And allow things like this:

```
void foo(int *x) {
    std::cout << *x << std::endl;
}

foo(&lvalue(5));
```

I'd like to be sure whether I'm invoking undefined-behavior or not in any of this, because I don't see any, although there may be some casting rule that would turn it illegal (which I ignore). Regarding lifetime of temporaries, I don't see a problem since, AFAIK, [rvalues live until the end of full-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/584835/1000282) and usage of the function is restricted to that.

There's a recent change to the standard about `reinterpret_cast` and `xvalues`
that seems to be on topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26793404/1000282

**EDIT**:

Better version using reference collapsing as suggested:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T &lvalue(T &&r) noexcept { return r; }
```

Comment: You are fine. The only thing which you can easier screw up by casting xvalues  to lvalues is lifetime issues, and you are right there's no danger in your examples, as the temporary is not referenced beyond the statement creating it. (The `reinterpret_cast`-proposal does not actually touch on your question.)

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks, I stated rvalues instead of specifically xvalues, because the question also includes expressions like `&lvalue(5)`. Which by the way is working fine.

Comment: BTW: Why do you use `std::remove_reference_t` instead of reference-collapsing rules?

Comment: @Deduplicator Because the code was based on libc++ `std::move` :-). Any terser improvement on it? I would like to know, I didn't care to think further how to turn it simpler, but I had a suspicion.

Comment: Passing a prvalue works, because it is copied to a temporary, which is passed by xvalue-reference to your function, and that temporary will only be destroyed at the end of the full expression, like the rest. About the improvement in brevity: return-value instead of `std::remove_reference_t<T> &` `T&`. BTW: I call mine `no_move`, and it's also useful for default-arguments.

Comment: The casting is not a problem here, because casts between lvalue refs and rvalue refs, is well-defined in both directions. And for the life-time, you just have to be careful with that, use it conservatively, and document the life-time expectations correctly,.. which is pretty much the same caution you would apply when taking the address of a reference or const-reference.

Comment: @Deduplicator I guess reference collapsing would make `template <typename T> inline constexpr auto &lvalue(T &&r) noexcept {return static_cast<T &>(r);}` work the same?

Comment: @pepper_chico: Yes. BTW: The `static_cast` is also superfluous.

Comment: @Deduplicator thanks for proof-checking.

Comment: BTW: The `inline` is implied by `constexpr`.

Comment: @Deduplicator ah, it came from libc++, since there, `constexpr` is not used, but a macro for it (for platforms where it may be absent).

Comment: But where temporary from `lvalue(std::ifstream("myfile.txt"))` dies? Is there dangling reference?

Comment: @Orient it's an interesting question. It seems particularly not important in this case because the iterator is used just to construct the string object by copying data, and ifstream lives for that task at last, and it's not used afterwards anywhere.

Comment: @Orient it should be dead at end of full expression, meaning on return of `get_my_file` it's dead, but string is already constructed with its own data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you said, you took care to not let any pointer or reference to the temporaries escape their scope.
Using your `lvalue`-function (mine is called `no_move`) makes it easier to break that stricture inadvertently.

Next, let's look at what `xvalues` are: Expiring objects, but objects nevertheless.
This means, you can ignore they are on their funeral tour (if you pass them to a function, that function will naturally do so, unless you ask to take advantage).

The last point you mentioned was calling with a prvalue, which is most certainly not an object.
But even that is not a problem, as on calling the function, a temporary will be created.
And that temporary will naturally also survive to the end of the statement.

As an aside, using `std::remove_reference_t<T>&` is unneccessary for the return-type of `lvalue`, you can use `T&` directly and rely on the reference-collapsing-rules. Also, the `static_cast` and `inline` are superfluous.

```
template <typename T> constexpr T& lvalue(T&& r) noexcept {return r;}
```