# Why are the compiler errors inconsistent in gcc and clang when casting an xvalue to a non-const lvalue reference?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, clang++

Can someone explain why both compilers throw an error on the second example whereas only gcc throws an error on the first example? Is it somehow related to the result of the `static_cast` being an xvalue?

```
int& example1 = reinterpret_cast<int&>(static_cast<int&&>(10));
//(gcc 10.2) error: invalid cast of an rvalue expression of type 'int' to type 'int&'
//(clang 11.0.0) no errors

int& example2 = reinterpret_cast<int&>(10);
//(gcc 10.2) error: invalid cast of an rvalue expression of type 'int' to type 'int&'
//(clang 11.0.0) error: reinterpret_cast from rvalue to reference type 'int &'
```

Also I'm not sure but I think the first example is well-formed because according to the standard, an xvalue is a type of a glvalue, right? And this [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.reinterpret.cast#11) part of the standard says that I should be able to cast T1 glvalues to the type “reference to T2” with the T1 being the same type as T2 in this case.

Comment: A compiler variance is pretty good for a first question to stackoverflow.

Comment: Just a guess, but misusing `reinterpret_cast` might just not require any diagnostics?

Comment: @Surt I removed it again, because results seem to be inconsistent. When I reload the page gcc randomly reports the error or not. Hre is my link again https://godbolt.org/z/48rqds

Comment: @Surt I saw all gcc versions i tested report the error, now I see 3 out of 5 versions report the error and before I had only 1 out of the 5 report the error. All that just by reloading the page. The issue seems to be more interesting than I first assumed

Comment: @lubgr So, I'm not really sure but I think it's not a misuse because according to the standard, an xvalue is a type of a glvalue, right? And this https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#11 part of the standard says that I should be able to cast T1 glvalues to the type “reference to T2” with the T1 being the same type as T2 in this case. But then again, I'm definitely not sure so I'd be glad if someone could back this claim of mine.

Comment: @SnakePin perhaps add that to your question. Comments are easily overlooked and are not permanent, they can vanish at any time

Comment: @idclev463035818 This is brilliant!! I reloaded that demo 5 times, and got at least 4 different results :)

Comment: I've edited in your comment since it's relevant, and a posted answer already refers to that.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I think we should close this as a dupe to the Q&A you proposed.

Comment: @dfrib But the body of the question is more like about why `reinterpret_cast<int&>(10)` is ill-formed :D

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Yes possibly that was a bit confusing, but from the comments to my answer it seems OP actually was more interested in `reinterpret_cast<int&>(std::move(10));`; I guess it doesn't hurt to have these two Q&A:s connected by a dupe link :)

Comment: @dfrib I've edited the question's body and title, is it more clear now?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer By the way, quite unrelated but you said "an xvalue is a type of a glvalue No." but the standard certainly says that an xvalue is a glvalue https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lval#1.3. I'm sure you know this but I think there's been a misunderstanding.

Comment: Misread as "rvalue is a glvalue".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> reinterpret_cast<int&>(10);
> ```

This program is ill-formed, as the expression being converted from is a prvalue. From [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.reinterpret.cast#1):

> The result of the expression `reinterpret_­cast<T>(v)` is the result of converting the expression `v` to type `T`. **If `T` is an lvalue reference type** or an rvalue reference to function type, **the result is an lvalue**; [...] Conversions that can be performed explicitly using `reinterpret_­cast` are listed below. **No other conversion can be performed explicitly** using `reinterpret_­cast`.

None of the clauses that follows allows a `reinterpret_cast` from a (p)rvalue that is not a pointer.

---

```
#include <memory>
reinterpret_cast<int&>(std::move(10));
```

Here, the expression being converted from is an xvalue, and as shown in the Q&A linked to [in a comment by @LanguageLawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64892562/why-isnt-clang-throwing-an-error-when-casting-an-xvalue-to-a-non-const-lvalue-r#comment114733864_64892562) (which is arguably a dupe target for this Q&A)

- [Can reinterpret_cast (or any cast) convert xvalues to lvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26793072/can-reinterpret-cast-or-any-cast-convert-xvalues-to-lvalues/)

this is well-formed, as of C++14 (updated as a DR fix also to C++11) and *the actual implementation of* [CWG 1268](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1268):

> **1268. reinterpret_cast of an xvalue operand** Section: 8.2.10  [expr.reinterpret.cast]
>
> Status: CD3
>
> Submitter: Michael Wong
>
> Date: 2011-03-21
>
> [Moved to DR at the October, 2012 meeting.]
>
> 8.2.10 [expr.reinterpret.cast] paragraph 11, dealing with casting to reference types, only allows an lvalue operand. Presumably it should
> allow a glvalue operand **when the target is an rvalue reference
> type.**
>
> [...]

Note that the emphasized segment proposes to allow this only when the target is an rvalue reference, but the actually updated [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.reinterpret.cast#11) removed this restriction.

Consequently, GCC is wrong to reject the first example.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224763/discussion-on-answer-by-dfrib-why-are-the-compiler-errors-inconsistent-in-gcc-an).